# Определить, содержится ли картинка в RichTextBox C# (WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Передо мной встала вот такая задача: определить есть ли в RichTextBox изображения. Каким образом я могу произвести операцию проверки?

*Может быть есть что-то по типу такого:*

`if (RichTextBox.Contains(Image))`?

При проверке символов в RichTextBox.Text объект типа Image преобразуется в " " (пробел). Как можно корректно проверить наличие картинки?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10430415/5045688

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да, я видел код на Visual Basic, но как это осуществить на c#?

Comment: Абсолютно так же!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оказалось, можно произвести проверку так:

`if (RichTextBox.Rtf.Contains("{\\sv Image}"))`

`if (RichTextBox.Rtf.Contains(@"\pict\wmetafile8\")` - не подходит (в отличие от Visual Basic), поскольку если вставить просто картинку, без текста, то данная строка не срабатывает (зато она срабатывает, если просто вписать текст в RichTextBox - \pict\wmetafile8).

По итогу, чтобы проверка выполнилась корректно, нужно использовать именно первую строку.